# adding geom_hline+ Sample Size to a boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using `ggplot`, I am trying to

1. add a horizontal line to boxplot
2. add the sample size to x axis.

I have the following dataset:

```
Site, Aluminum_Dissolved, Federal_Guideline
M1, 0.1, 0.4
M1, 0.2, 0.4
M1, 0.5, 0.4
M2, 0.6, 0.4
M2, 0.4, 0.4
M2, 0.3, 0.4
```

#### adding a horizontal line

```
#Make a boxplot with horizontal error bars
ggplot(ExampleData, aes(x = Site,y = Aluminum_Dissolved))+
    stat_boxplot(geom='errorbar', linetype=1)+
    geom_boxplot(fill="pink")

#Now want to add guideline value at 0.4 with corresponding "Federal Guideline" in legend, I tried:
geom_hline(0.4)
```

And I get the following error:

> Error in get(x, envir = this, inherits = inh)(this, ...) : 
>     Mapping should be a list of unevaluated mappings created by aes or aes_string

I tried adding data in string i.e., `geom_hline("ExampleData$Federal_Guideline)` but I get same error as above.

#### Adding sample size (n= to x axis):

Finally, I want to add n to the label of the x-axis (i.e., `M2 (n=3)`).  I am able to do this in regular R, with the following code: `names=paste(b$names, "(n=", b$n,")"))`, where `b`=`boxplot` function, but I can't figure out how to do this in `ggplot2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly name the arguments in `geom_hline`, otherwise it doesn't know to what `0.4` is referring.

So

```
ggplot(ExampleData, aes(x = Site,y = Aluminum_Dissolved))+
    stat_boxplot(geom='errorbar', linetype=1)+
    geom_boxplot(fill="pink") +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0.4)
```

Will produce your required horizontal line.

To change the labels on the x-axis, use `scale_x_discrete` to change the labels

You can precompute these  using  something like

```
library(plyr)
xlabels <- ddply(ExampleData, .(Site), summarize, 
                 xlabels = paste(unique(Site), '\n(n = ', length(Site),')'))

ggplot(ExampleData, aes(x = Site,y = Aluminum_Dissolved))+
     stat_boxplot(geom='errorbar', linetype=1)+
     geom_boxplot(fill="pink") + geom_hline(yintercept = 0.4) + 
      scale_x_discrete(labels = xlabels[['xlabels']])
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your clear editing and answers!  I have added + geom_hline(yintercept=0.4, linetype=2, colour="red") to get the line i was looking for.  I have tried adding: show_guide=TRUE to get the legend to show up, but to no avail.  Am i making some kind of syntax error?

Comment: Also, the 'n' coding works beautifully ... thanks.  I would not have figured that out myself.